# How to access the last element of a reverse array?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

If I have a current array listed in REVERSE by simply changing it in html where it is iterating through the indexes:

```
arrayName.length - i - 1
```

How would I be able to access just the last array of the element??? Below is the line of statement I tried which fails since we are iterating through the indexes( getting console.log value through every iteration).

```
arrayName.length - 1 === i
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Seems that this can be done in various ways, depending on the way you iterate in template.

Comment: why are you doing `=== i` ??

Comment: Because I only want the result of the console.log to show when the total length of the array is equal to the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to access to last element in array in .html will be:
*ngFor="let item of items; let last = last"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of reverseArray, let i = index">
 {{ 'index: '+ i }} {{ i === reverseArray.length -1 ? 'Last element of the reverse array: "' + item + '"' : '"' + item + '"'  }}
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  arrayName = [ 11, 89, 23, 7, 98 ];
  reverseArray = [...this.arrayName].reverse();

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.reverseArray);  
  }
 
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]